# One many reference flask_restx Dto

Tags: flask-restful

I have a problem in Dto. I want have in two model reference between each but I have an error due to declaration order. : NameError: name 'b' is not defined

```
class AADto:
   api = Namespace('aa', description='aa related operations')
   a = api.model('a', {
       'id': fields.Integer(required=True, description='a id'),
       'b': fields.Nested(b),
   }),
   b = api.model('b', {
       'id': fields.Integer(required=True, description='b id'),
       'aArray': fields.List(fields.Nested(a)),
   }),
```

Someone have documentation for this case or an answer for how have reference between each ?

Thanks.

Comment: Some one .....?

Answer (score 0):

So I use Integer for b attribute of a. So attribute b became an b_id.

```
class AADto:
   api = Namespace('aa', description='aa related operations')
   a = api.model('a', {
       'id': fields.Integer(required=True, description='a id'),
       'b_id': fields.Integer(required=False, description='b id'),
   }),
   b = api.model('b', {
       'id': fields.Integer(required=True, description='b id'),
       'aArray': fields.List(fields.Nested(a)),
   }),
```